# How do I validate that an entered value is greater than all other cells in a range above but relative to this cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want to have a list of values that can be modified by a user, but is in ascending order, and can skip values, so `4, 6, 12, 15, 21` should validate, but changing `15` to `11` should trigger the error.

I tried to have the cells validate by comparing their value to the range of cells above it, so cells `F5:F10` have the validation formula `F5>Max($F$4:F4)`. This formula, as suggested for making such formulas, works fine when put into cells adjacent to the cells I want to validate, but does not work in the validation, as any value (less or greater than the ones above) causes an error.

I tried troubleshooting by changing the direction of the comparison to `F5<Max($F$4:F4)` and still every value I try fails validation.

Is there a tweak for what I'm trying to do? Different function? Am I going in completely the wrong direction?

Comment: Data validation?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if your =Max() works. There are a lot of alternatives to solving this. I think the simplest is testing that each pair is ascending (f1>f2, f2>f3, f3>f4, etc). then wrapping this up into an overall formula that gives you the appropriate message.

Comment: good enough point, I suppose, with the simply comparing to cell above - max isn't necessary, if all the rules are actually enforced, but I tried and it still doesn't work - I think at this point I must be looking for troubleshooting steps, because I think I'm trying to fix the wrong issue